# Synchronized block still locked after thread restart

Tags: java, synchronized-block

I try to restart thread but synchronized block in thread keep locked after restarted. I shouldn't change socket properties because some processes take too long but when network connection lost it hangs forever. I try to use InterruptedException but it doesn't work. Is there any way to release this lock?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        synchronizedBlock t1 = new synchronizedBlock();
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t1.cancel();
        t1 = new synchronizedBlock();
        t1.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (true) {

    }
}

public class synchronizedBlock extends Thread {

   boolean isRunning = true;
   boolean isRunning2 = true;
   public static Object[] locks = new Object[5];

   public synchronizedBlock() {
       for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           synchronizedBlock.locks[i] = i;
       }
   }

   public void cancel() {
       isRunning = false;
       interrupt();
   }

   public void socketProces() {
       while (isRunning2) {
       }
   }

   public void proces(int index) {
       try {
           synchronized (locks[index]) {
               System.out.println("Synchronized Block Begin");
               socketProces();
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       try {
           System.out.println("Run begin");
           while (isRunning) {
               proces(1);
           }
           Thread.sleep(1);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           //Do Something
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
Run begin
Synchronized Block Begin
Run begin
```

Comment: Class names should start in uppercase so they don't get confused with variable names, which start in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the `synchronizedBlock` thread you'll get a stack trace like this I think:
`run` -> `proces` -> `socketProcess`.
Then because `isRunning2 = true`, the thread will enter an infinite loop in `socketProcess` and never terminate.

Keep in mind that in Java there is no such thing as 'restarting' a `thread`. Once started, a thread can never be restarted. Indeed, you are creating two `sycnchronizedBlock` objects, not restarting a single object.

As a side note, it is generally problematic to overwrite static state in a class constructor, as you're doing with the `locks` variable, without synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the [`Integer` cache](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) which is used in the `for` loop to initialize the `synchronizedBlock.locks` array:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    synchronizedBlock.locks[i] = i;
}
```

When this code is run again, due to the constructor of the second `synchronizedBlock`, the `synchronizedBlock.locks` array contains the **same** `Integer` instances which where created when this `for` loop was executed for the first time. This means that the `synchronized (locks[index])` lock will be on the **same** `Integer` object. As you have already one thread holding the lock for the `Integer(1)` object, the second thread waits outside the `lock` waiting for it to be released.

This is also problematic in combination with the fact that the first thread is not terminating. Your method

```
public void socketProces() {
    while (isRunning2) {
    }
}
```

is an endless loop as you don't change the value of `isRunning2`, ever. Also, the [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())  method itself does not stop any thread. Instead, it sets just an internal flag in the `Thread` class, which can be checked with [`isInterrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) and [`interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()). You have to check this flag and react on it like "Oh, someone wants me to stop, so I stop now".

To solve your problem you should at least quit your thread when the "isInterrupted" flag of the `Thread` instance is set. You can do it like this:

```
public void socketProces() {
    while (isRunning2) {
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of returning from `socketProces()` normally you could throw an `InterruptedException` like other methods do.

Also, depending on how you want to initialize/use the instances you want to lock on with `synchronized(...)`, you might want to consider on how you create/fill the `synchronizedBlock.locks` array and which objects you want to use (the `Integer` cache might be problematic here). It depends on you if the  creation of a new `synchronizedBlock` instance will/should/shouldn't create new objects to lock on in the `synchronizedBlock.locks` array.